# Default positional arguments in C++11 templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

It's allowed to leave template arguments blank (using <>), how would you leave a positional argument blank or rework this to achieve the same effect.

```
template <int i = 0, int j = 1, int k = 2>
void blah() {
    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    blah();        // ok
    blah<>();      // ok
    blah<1>();     // ok, i = 1
    blah<1,,3>();  // not ok, i = 1, j = 1 (default), k = 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not possible to do like you can in python, the arguments are identified by position not by any identifier as such

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. You have to pass it.

Here is a suggestion:

```
auto constexpr default_j = 1;

template <int i = 0, int j = default_j, int k = 2>
void blah() {
    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    blah();                  // ok
    blah<>();                // ok
    blah<1>();               // ok, i = 0
    blah<1, default_j, 3>(); // ok, explicit and without duplicate magic numbers!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Fun with macros (do not try this at home, kids):

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i = 0, int j = 1, int k = 2>
void blah() {
    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
}

#define _blah(D, V) (*#V ? V + 0 : D)
#define blah_3(I,J,K) blah<_blah(0,I), _blah(1,J), _blah(2,K)>()
#define blah_2(I,J) blah_3(I,J,)
#define blah_1(I) blah_3(I,,)
#define blah__(_1,_2,_3,X,...) blah ## X
#define blah(...) blah__(__VA_ARGS__,_3,_2,_1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    blah();
    blah(, ,);
    blah(1);
    blah(1,,);
    blah(1, ,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: …And when the parents came home they were horrified.

Comment: …They grounded him for 2 weeks.